# Django retrieve data from multiple tables

Tags: django, orm

I have two MySQL models:

```
class registration(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   email = models.EmailField()
   password = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   company = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class personal_details(models.Model):
   reg = models.ForeignKey(registration)
   job = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   experience = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I want to filtering details using both experience and company as a keyword. I want to fetch and display details(name, email, company, job, experience) from both tables in my HTML page.

Comment: Please explain more about your problem! What's it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
details = personal_details.objects.filter(experience=1, 
    reg__company="YourCompany").select_related()

{% for detail in details %}
    Name: {{ detail.reg.name }}
    Email: {{ detail.reg.email }}
    Company: {{ detail.reg.company }}
    Job: {{ detail.job }}
    Experience: {{ detail.experience }}<br/>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: its not worked.. jobs only displayed name and email not displayed.. give some more tips..

Comment: oh sorry, it must be `reg` not `registration`

Comment: thanks i have updated my question, refer that and post your answer

Answer (score 2):

Without a more in-depth explanation of your problem, it's hard to answer your question properly, but here goes:

One option:

```
# views.py
def mypage(request):

    details = Personal_details.objects.select_related().filter(experience=3)
    names = [d.reg.name for d in details]

    return render(request, 'mypage.html', {'names': names})

# html

<p>People with 3 experience:</p>
<ul>
    {% for name in names %}
        <li>{{ name }}</li>
    {% empty %}
        <li>Nobody has 3 experience!</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Another option:

```
# views.py
def mypage(request):

    details = Personal_details.objects.select_related().all()
    names = [d.reg.name for d in details]
    info = zip(details, names)

    return render(request, 'mypage.html', {'info': info})

#html

<ul>
    {% for detail, name in info %}
        {% if detail.experience == 0 %}
            <li>{{ name }} has 0 experience</li>
        %{ elif detail.experience == 1 %}
            <li>{{ name }} has 1 experience</li>
        # and so on and so forth....
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**Note** how I capitalised your model (i.e. class) names. This is convention and you should stick to it.

So this may or may not be what you are hoping to do, and it probably isn't the best way to go about it, but hopefully it will get you started on your own solution. I recommend reading up on Django [views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/overview/#write-your-views) and [template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/).

Answer (score 1):

First get a list of personal_details (with experience qual to 9) like this:

```
p_details_list = personal_details.objects.filter(experience=9)
```

After that you can acces each element's `reg` attribute, and it will give you the corresponding `registration` object

Comment: There is a `select_related` method on queryset that will fetch data from both tables. For example above `personal_details.objects.filter(experience=9).select_related('reg')` will fetch both personal_details and registration data at once.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want data wise, but you can pull the data from the `personal_details` objects ForeignKey relationship in two ways.

With reverse relationship go via the `_set` and I'm just shooting from the hip here:

```
reg = registration.objects.get(pk=1)
print reg.personaldetails_set.job
```

Otherwise, via the normal FK way.

```
details = personal_details.objects.get(pk=1)
print details.reg.name
```