# DJANGO - Filter Data from two models

Tags: django

I have two MySQL models:

```
class registration(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   email = models.EmailField()
   password = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   company = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class personal_details(models.Model):
   reg = models.ForeignKey(registration)
   job = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   experience = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I want to filtering details using both experience and company as a keyword. I want to fetch and display details(name, email, company, job, experience) from both tables in my HTML page.

Comment: You asked this exact same question yesterday, want to revise it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15812876/django-reterive-data-from-multiple-tables/15813017#15813017

Comment: yesterday i asked to filter with only experience. today i'm trying to filter with experience and company both keywords are in different models... give some idea for me

Comment: I would recommend you do the Django tutorial, it will help you do these things very quickly!

Comment: ya i learned, but when trying with multiple tables there is some difficulties arise...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it inside the `filter()` so you should do something like this

I'm working from the `personal_details` object now:

```
filteredResults = personal_details.objects.filter(experience="grasscutting", reg__company="IBM")
```

This will give you a list of objects found.
The magic here is that you can access ForeignKey relationships with the `__` convention.